# Unhiding/Unlocking Files Locked By File Locker Shell For NTFS

Tags: windows-8, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions, lock

I locked an important folder with "locker for NTFS" from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flockshell4ntfs/files/), but now that it is hidden and locked, the unlocking doesn't work. I have tried using `cmd` and looked for some tutorials but none have worked. I remember the path for the folder and gaining access to the folder is easy, but how can I make it appear and unhidden again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool is using built in permissions and file attributes to hide and lock files.

Judging from a comment of  `My folder will not unlock. Very bad. Posted 08/03/2016` on the project website, it would seem that the program is not complete, or instructions were not followed.

First, to view the hidden file(s)/folder(s) in question:

Click on `❖ Start` → Click on `Search` → Type in: `Folder Options` → Click the `Folder Options` listing → Select the `View` tab → Tick `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`.

If your file(s)/folder(s) do not show, also untick `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` in case the software marks them as "system" files.

**EDIT:** As indicated in the comments section, the locking seems to be with the built-in security settings with Windows. Users will see a generic "Access Denied" message. You will need to change the file/folder security settings to get around this.

Attempting to change the security settings of the folder/file in question you will see this, instead of the normal, simple, and more familiar security settings window:
[image: Advanced security settings window]

What you will have to do is add either your group or username to have "full control" permissions.

Click the `Continue` button to escalate your privileges → Click `Add` → Click the `Select a principle` link. After that you will have to enter your fully qualified username/group. Clicking on `Check Names` will help you resolve it. Click `OK` when you are done.

**If you do not see a "Continue" button**, change the owner instead.
[image: Username entry window]

After that is complete, you will then tick the `Full control` permission, which will tick all of the permissions below. Click `OK` → `Apply` → `OK`:
[image: Permissions window]

You should be able to enter the folder or access the file. If you are unable to, verify your permissions again.

Web Links:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/flockshell4ntfs/

Comment: the folder is partial visible, there's a bit of transparency, however it seems to be different in windows 8 to get access to the folder. In windows 7, there was a tab to get permissions to access the folder, which seems gone in windows eight. I had locked the folder by using the same application. How can I regain access to it?

Comment: @bzal What do you mean "locked"? Does it show an error message? Can you link to an image of the error message?

Comment: it says access denied. Back when I was using windows 7, I could right click on it, and head to security tabs and change permissions and I gained access to it. But, such seems to be gone in windows 8.1.

Comment: @bzal I don't think it has gone anywhere: https://s28.postimg.org/4pk8mwl4t/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: I don't know if it's a different version of windows, but mine's definitely not showing that:

Comment: https://s30.postimg.org/epi9jgsb5/image.png

Comment: @bzal Here's a quick crash course in 2 images. On that page go "Continue" then click "Add", then "Select a principal": https://s30.postimg.org/sj1qqu0up/Untitled_1.jpg then https://s30.postimg.org/4gkwvyk7l/Untitled_2.jpg then OK, and then Apply. Access should be granted.

Comment: the window disappears after I hit continue, and after I hit change, weird window appears. There's no point that I can select a principal:  https://s30.postimg.org/f11s4i0n5/Untitled.png

Comment: @bzal In that window you will need to enter your username, then click "Check Names". After that, Click OK, then Apply, then OK again.

Comment: I hope I was not irritatingly persistent, but finally, done, thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 0):

Try out my Batch Folder Locker script:

```
@echo off & title Folder Locker & pushd "%~dp0" & color 0a
::****************************************************************
openfiles >nul 2>&1 & if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion & color 4f
  echo Running Admin Shell, Please wait.... & ping localhost -n 1 >nul
  set "bPath=%~f0" & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
  echo Dim UAC : Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) >Elevate.vbs
  echo For Each strArg in Wscript.Arguments >>Elevate.vbs
  echo   args = args ^& strArg ^& " " >>Elevate.vbs
  echo Next >>Elevate.vbs
  echo UAC.ShellExecute "!bPath!",args,"","runas",1 >>Elevate.vbs
  echo Set objShell = Nothing >>Elevate.vbs
  cscript //nologo Elevate.vbs & del Elevate.vbs & exit /b
)
::****************************************************************
if not exist "%userprofile%\desktop\%~n0.lnk" (
  (
  echo Call Shortcut("%~f0","Folder Locker"^)
  echo Sub Shortcut(Application,Name^)
  echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
  echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
  echo    MyTab = Split(Application,"\"^)
  echo    If Name = "" Then
  echo      Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
  echo    End if
  echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
  echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Name ^& ".lnk"^)
  echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Chr(34^) ^& Application ^& Chr(34^)
  echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "shell32.dll,47"
  echo    objShortCut.Save
  echo End Sub
  ) >>crshort.vbs
  cscript //nologo crshort.vbs & del crshort.vbs
)
::**************************************************************
mode 160,40
if not exist "%userprofile%\id.spfile" goto first_lock
goto :Unlocker_Password
:first_lock
cls & echo. & echo.
echo                              #########################################
echo                                      Welcome to Folder Locker
echo                              #########################################
echo. 
echo No Private Folder was found, a folder is needed to be created
echo.
Call :InputPassword "Create a strong password for the locker"
::**************************************************************
cls & echo. & echo.
echo Please choose a folder where to create the locker, a dialog box will come:
Call :ChooseFolder "%Userprofile%\Desktop" "Choose the folder where the hidden folder locker will be created, preffereably choose an unpredictable secure location, though it will be completely hidden"
cls
::**************************************************************
echo             #########################################################################
echo                            Creating the private folder, please wait.....
echo             #########################################################################
echo.
type nul >"%userprofile%\id.spfile"
md "%folder%\SecretLocker" & md "%AppData%\Wasif"
echo %password% >"%AppData%\Wasif\pwd.spfile"
echo %folder% >"%AppData%\Wasif\folder.spfile"
call :LockFolder "%AppData%" "Wasif"
call :LockFolder "%folder%" "SecretLocker"
ping localhost -n 2 -w 1000 >nul 2>&1
::*************************************************************
cls
echo Creation of the private folder was done
echo To work with the folder, re-launch this (%~nx0) batch file
echo Then input the password again and options will come
echo.
pause >nul | echo Press any key to quit.....
exit /b 0
::***********************************************************

:Unlocker_Password
::***********************************************************
cls & echo. & echo.
Call :InputPassword "Enter your password"
Call :UnlockFolder "%Appdata%" "Wasif" False
set /p actpassword=<"%Appdata%\Wasif\pwd.spfile"
if %actpassword%==%password% (goto :Unlocker_Menu)
goto :Bad_Password
::***********************************************************
:Bad_Password
color 0c & cls
echo Bad password entered
pause >nul | echo Press any key to quit.....
Call :LockFolder "%Appdata%" "Wasif"
exit /b 0
::***********************************************************
:Unlocker_Menu
cls & color 0a & echo. & echo.
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type "%Appdata%\Wasif\folder.spfile"') do set "folder=%%a"
echo                      ###################################
echo                              Folder Locker Menu
echo                      ###################################
echo                Private folder is in: %folder:~0,-1%
echo.
echo [1] Unlock Private folder
echo [2] Unlock Private folder and open in explorer
echo [3] Change password
echo [4] Delete Private folder
echo [5] Lock and Quit (Recommended you quit from here)
choice /c 12345 /n
goto %errorlevel%
::***********************************************************
:1
Call :UnlockFolder "%folder:~0,-1%" "SecretLocker" False
cls & echo Unlocked!
pause & Goto :Unlocker_Menu
::***********************************************************
:2
Call :UnlockFolder "%folder:~0,-1%" "SecretLocker" True
cls & echo Unlocked!
pause & Goto :Unlocker_Menu
::***********************************************************
:3
Call :InputPassword "Enter new password"
echo %password% >"%Appdata%\Wasif\pwd.spfile"
cls & echo Changed password!
pause & goto :Unlocker_Menu
::***********************************************************
:4
Call :Unlock_Folder "%folder:~0,-1%" "SecretLocker" False
rd /s /q "%folder:~0,-1%\SecretLocker"
rd /s /q "%Appdata%\Wasif"
del /f /q "%userprofile%\id.spfile"
cls & echo Deletion was successful!
pause >nul | echo Press any key to quit...
exit /b 0
::***********************************************************
:5
Call :LockFolder "%Appdata%" "Wasif"
Call :LockFolder "%folder:~0,-1%" "SecretLocker"
exit /b 0
::***********************************************************

:: Functions                      
::************************************************************
:ChooseFolder <StrInitialFolderPath> <StrDescription> 
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms;$f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;$f.SelectedPath='%~1';$f.Description='%~2';$f.ShowDialog();$f.SelectedPath}"`) do set "folder=%%a"
exit /b 0
::************************************************************
:LockFolder <StrParentFolderPath> <StrFolderName>
set "alias=AnonymousHacker.{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}"
ren "%~1\%~2" "%alias%" >nul 2>&1 & attrib +r +s +h "%~1\%alias%" >nul 2>&1
icacls "%~1\%alias%" /deny Users:F >nul 2>&1 & exit /b 0
::************************************************************
:UnlockFolder <StrParentFolderPath> <StrOldFolderName> <BoolOpenInExplorer>
set "alias=AnonymousHacker.{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}"
icacls "%~1\%alias%" /grant Users:F >nul 2>&1 & attrib -r -s -h "%~1\%alias%" >nul 2>&1
ren "%~1\%alias%" "%~2" >nul 2>&1 & if '%~3'=='True' (explorer "%~1\%~2") 
exit /b 0
::************************************************************
:InputPassword <StrPrompt>
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command "& {$Password=read-host '%~1' -AsSecureString;$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password);[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)}"') do set "password=%%a"
exit /b 0
::************************************************************
```

This will create a Private folder and prompt user to choose a password and location.

- It will rename the private folder to `AnonymousHacker.{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}` which will replace contents with PrintHood.
- Then add attributes Read-Only,Hidden and System file.
- Then deny Users group full access on it.

It can unlock and open the folder when needed if you input password in the batch file. Also change password and remove it. Creates a desktop shortcut.